# Going backwards in regex Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have been trying at this all day, and can't find a solution. Here is my current code:

```
stranger = re.search(r"Stranger:</strong> <span>.+?</span></p></div></div></div>", html2)
```

I am wanting an outcome like this:

```
"Stranger:</strong> <span>What now?</span></p></div></div></div>" = True
```

from a string like this:

```
"<div class=\"logitem\"><p class=\"strangermsg\"><strong class=\"msgsource\">Stranger:</strong> <span>Wow</span></p></div><div class=\"logitem\"><p class=\"youmsg\"><strong class="msgsource">You:</strong> <span>Eek</span></p></div><div class=\"logitem\"><p class=\"strangermsg\"><strong class=\"msgsource\">Stranger:</strong> <span>What now?</span></p></div></div></div>"
```

Instead I get this:

```
"Stranger:</strong> <span>Wow</span></p></div><div class=\"logitem\"><p class=\"youmsg\"><strong class=\"msgsource\">You:</strong> <span>Eek</span></p></div><div class=\"logitem\"><p class=\"strangermsg\"><strong class=\"msgsource\">Stranger:</strong> <span>What now?</span></p></div></div></div>" = True
```

Basically I am wanting to get everything from before the "/span p div div div" and after the *previous* instance of "span" (no /). I've tried all kinds of things, but I don't know what I could possibly do. Anyone able to help here?

Comment: Don't use a regular expression to parse HTML. Use a DOM parser like Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying that between the two inner tags, don't allow special control sequences. For example,

```
stranger = re.search(r"Stranger:</strong> <span>[^<>]+?</span></p></div></div></div>", html2)
```

This means that whatever is between those two inner tags, there cannot be other `<` or `>` characters.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, now the code is not catching instances within the last "Stranger:" of line breaks, like, for instance, the response "Hi<br>I'm Mike!". Is there any way to fix it so that it makes an exception for line breaks, only in that particular section of the string?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to match. If the only html you want to match is <br>, then you could exclude tags that begin with "</" by using a negative lookahead: `"((?!</).)"`. However, if your requirements are so complicated, it may be better to use a different parser instead of regex.